# Robot semantic description not found

Tags: ros, moveit, rosparam, robot-description, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not able to use this command on baxter. :

```
group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("left_arm") 
gives error: RuntimeError: Group 'left_arm' was not found.
```

The website tutorial of baxter claims that  *The SRDF is generated dynamically at runtime and then loaded to the param server under robot_semantic_description.* But, I am getting the following error:

```
 [ERROR] [1490907690.019375241]: Robot semantic description not found. Did you forget to define or remap '/robot_description_semantic'?
```

I am able to see 'rosparam get /robot_description', but there is no rosparam as /robot_semantic_description

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258298/robot-semantic-description-not-found/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) on 2017-07-12**:
I'm getting this same error message using a Turtlebot 2 with a PhantomX Pincher, the turtlebot_arm repo and the pick_and_place.py demos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

short answer:

did you forgot to launch move_group.launch !?

long answer:

Answering in a  robot agnostic way, because this can happen not only with Baxter but with other robots as well...

The srdf file is autogenerated by moveit setup assistant and located under `my_moveit_config_pkg/config/my_robot_name.srdf`

It gets loaded into the parameter server by the file `my_moveit_config_pkg/launch/planning_context.launch`
specifically in the line :

```
<!-- The semantic description that corresponds to the URDF -->
  <param name="$(arg robot_description)_semantic" textfile="$(find my_moveit_config_pkg)/config/my_robot_name.srdf" />
```

So if `/robot_semantic_description` param is not found in param server most probably you forgot to launch move_group.launch interface (that calls planning_context.launch), another possibility is that you have modified manually the moveit automatically generated files or probably is being pushed under a namespace (do `rosparam list | grep robot_semantic_description` to check)

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-10-11**:
Shouldn't it be `/robot_description_semantic`? (i.e. *description* followed by *semantic*)